# Php Undefined index

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have a user input form here. This is the code for it!

```
<form id="addCommentForm" method="POST" action="#">
    <div>

        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>"/>

        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

        <label for="email">Your Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

        <label for="body">Comment Body</label>
        <textarea name="bodytext" id="bodytext"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

but on submitting i get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: bodytext in /home/se212004/public_html/post-comment-mine.php on line 15
```

which refers to this block of code:

```
if (isset($_POST))
{

   $username = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $content = $_POST['bodytext'];
   $post_id=$_POST['post_id'];

   $lowercase = strtolower($email);
   $image = md5( $lowercase );

   //insert these values into the db as a new comment
   //example using array syntax to insert values
   $statement = "INSERT INTO comments (name, body, dt, email) VALUES (?, ?, now(), ?)";
   $sth = $db->prepare($statement);
   $data = array($username, $content, $email);
   $sth->execute($data);
}
```

The error is pointing at  `$content = $_POST['bodytext'];`. Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Here is javascript file.

```
$(function() {

$(".submit").click(function() {

var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var comment = $("#bodytext").val();
var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
var dataString = '&name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comment=' + comment +   '&post_id=' + post_id;


if(name=='' || email=='' || comment=='')
 {
alert('Please Give Valid JOE Details');
 }
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&     nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
  url: "post-comment-mine.php",
   data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){

  $("ol#update").append(html);
  $("ol#update li:last").fadeIn("slow");
  document.getElementById('email').value='';
  document.getElementById('name').value='';
  document.getElementById('comment').value='';
$("#name").focus();

  $("#flash").hide();

 }
});
}
return false;
});



});
```

Comment: You know about the syntax error of `=>` in your textarea HTML right?

Comment: It was a typo, it does not fix anything!

Comment: Do print_r $_POST in the block of PHP provided, and send me the output.

Comment: I tried doing that but the code just seizes up and does nothing. How should i do it?

Comment: this error is not possible, because your code is correct.. `<textarea name="bodytext" id="bodytext"></textarea>` and  `$content = $_POST['bodytext'];` it's OK!!!

Comment: Just a thought. How are you submitting the form? I'm asking because action is set to "#". If you change # to post-comment-mine.php. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Via a javascript file that takes over on clicking the submit button!

Comment: @JoeConnell - can you show us the js then? Or try to temporarily change # to the actual-filename. You should not get an error here, because the PHP and HTML seems ok. But js might be the js-code that screws it up...

Comment: @JoeConnell You have JS submitting the form but omitted it from the question when it directly pertains to it?  You should help us help you.

Comment: I have uploaded it as an edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
var dataString = '&name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comment=' + comment +   '&post_id=' + post_id;
```

You set `comment` value to the `bodytext` and in php you check `$_POST['bodytext']` when you should be checking `$_POST['comment']`, either that, or change the line to:

```
var dataString = '&name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&bodytext=' + comment +   '&post_id=' + post_id;
```

It should be noted that you need to properly encode the variables here as well when you submit them in this manner.

Comment: wow, i cannot believe i missed that!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case $_POST['bodytext'] is not set which causes php runtime error. After fixing the error replacde

```
$content = $_POST['bodytext'];
```

with

```
$content = isset($_POST['bodytext']) ? $_POST['bodytext'] : '';
```